# Service call returns bad gateway before it completes execution - Nodemailer not being awaited for completion

Tags: javascript, lambda, async-await, microservices, nodemailer

I am trying to fetch data from the Amazon SQS (queue service) which is loaded by another Micro service (Rest API). I am using the parameters and attributes from this data to send the email. The nodemailer sendMail is not being waited to complete its execution. I read in an SO Q&A that nodemailer supports callback and now also await(if Node version is higher than 8). But both of them are not working. The API call is returned before the completion of nodemailer's sendMail execution. The email is being sent and the API completes its execution. But the call is returned before the sendMail is completed.

I always get the 502 bad gateway response.

Below is the code for sendMail.

```js
  sendMail(body: MailObject): Promise < boolean > {
        const senderAddress: Mail.Address = {
            address: body.from.emailAddress,
            name: body.from.name ? body.from.name : ''
        }


        const recipientAddress: Mail.Address = {
            address: body.to.emailAddress,
            name: body.to.name ? body.to.name : ''
        }

        const mailOptions: Mail.Options = {
            from: senderAddress,
            to: recipientAddress,
            subject: body.subject,
            text: body.text ? body.text : undefined,
            html: body.html ? body.html : undefined,
            amp: body.html ? body.html : undefined
        }
        return new Promise<any> (async (resolve, reject) => {
            if (!this.transporter) {
                this.logger.warn(`Transporter not intitialized. Use connect method`);
                reject(`Transporter not initialized. Use connect method`);
            }
            console.log(`[location]: [sendMail][promise]`);
            console.log(`[Mail Options]: ${JSON.stringify(mailOptions)}`)
            this.transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, data)=>{  //<--- I have also tried await
                   if(error){
                       console.error(`[sendMail][error]: ${error}`);
                       reject(error);
                   }
                   else{
                       console.log(`[sendMail][data]: ${data}`);
                       resolve(true);
                   }
               })
            })
    }
```

Please refer to the below snippet of the final log. The http status of the returned value is 200. But it is logged after the API call returns a 502 bad gateway on ARC/postman.

[image: Log snippet]

The above response is logged after API call displays 502 bad gateway on postman.

Comment: Did you check your transporter and it's credentials if it's smtp  try to send mail from another client to ensure that your creds are valid. one like https://mxtoolbox.com/diagnostic.aspx

Comment: Hi @JustRaman, thank you for your reply. Yes its valid. The email is being sent. But the call to the API is not waiting for it to complete execution. The API continues its execution after the call is returned with a bad gateway response.

Comment: There is no problem with this part of your code. The problem is somewhere else. Make sure you await the call of sendMail in your outer functions.

Comment: Hi @Dani, You are right. Thanks figured out the reason. It got fixed when I added a promise to the data I am getting from SQS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dani mentioned in the comment section of the question, the issue wasn't in the above code. The issue was that it wasn't waiting for the service to complete fetching data from SQS.

Added promise to the receiveMessage function of AWS SQS (please refer to the comment for the first line of code).

```js
 this.sqs.receiveMessage(params).promise().then(async data=>{  //<--- Added promise here
                    console.log(`[MessageBody]: ${data.Messages![0].Body}`);
                    this.message = {
                      MessageId : data.Messages![0].MessageId||"",
                      ReceiptHandle : data.Messages![0].ReceiptHandle||"",
                      MD5OfBody : data.Messages![0].MD5OfBody||"",
                      Body : data.Messages![0].Body||"",
                      MD5OfMessageAttributes : data.Messages![0].MD5OfMessageAttributes||"",
                      MessageAttributes : {
                        from: {
                          StringValue: data.Messages![0].MessageAttributes!.from.StringValue||"",
                          StringListValues: data.Messages![0].MessageAttributes!.from.StringListValues||{},
                          BinaryListValues: data.Messages![0].MessageAttributes!.from.BinaryListValues||{},
                          DataType: data.Messages![0].MessageAttributes!.from.DataType||""
                        },
                        subject: {
                          StringValue: data.Messages![0].MessageAttributes!.subject.StringValue||"",
                          StringListValues: data.Messages![0].MessageAttributes!.subject.StringListValues||{},
                          BinaryListValues: data.Messages![0].MessageAttributes!.subject.BinaryListValues||{},
                          DataType: data.Messages![0].MessageAttributes!.subject.DataType||""
                        },
                        to: {
                          StringValue: data.Messages![0].MessageAttributes!.to.StringValue||"",
                          StringListValues: data.Messages![0].MessageAttributes!.to.StringListValues||{},
                          BinaryListValues: data.Messages![0].MessageAttributes!.to.BinaryListValues||{},
                          DataType: data.Messages![0].MessageAttributes!.to.DataType||""
                        }
                      }
                      
                    }
```